# Is$\ +\infty$ greater than any other number (surreal, superreal, hyperreal, ...)?

Tags: infinity, ordered-fields

Let$\ \mathbb{A}$ be an arbitrary totally ordered set and consider the largest element of the set of extended real numbers,$\ +\infty$. Can we say that$\ +\infty > \chi $, for *any*$\ \chi \in \mathbb{A}$?

Comment: Is $+\infty$ in $\mathbb A$? If not, I guess we could always adjoin it and define it to be bigger than anything else.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{A}$ an arbitrary totally ordered set _of_?  Without some restrictions you can't even make the comparison meaningful, and if $\mathbb{A}$ is a set of reals then the answer is trivial.

Comment: More to the point, the operator $\gt$ is part of the _structure_ under consideration; there is no 'universal' greater-than operator.  You can _interpret_ some of these structures within each other (e.g., the reals embed into each of them), but without defining the relation itself the question isn't sensible.

Comment: @Nishant No, it isn't. You might be right, after all it would be the same extension as that of the reals.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Oh, I'm sorry, this really is a question out of curiosity, I didn't know. And I don't know the conditions for my question to be sensitive, but postulating them, is the answer positive? Also, could what Nishant suggested be correct?

Comment: The only plausible answer is 'maybe'.  The key is that you need to define _all_ of the terms you're using - the structure, the entity $+\infty$, and the relation $\gt$.  Once you do that, you'll find that the answer shakes out trivially one way or the other - but which way it shakes out depends on what you choose as your specific definitions every step of the way.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I see. Then, what if$\ +\infty$ is the usual extended real number (the greatest of them), and$\ \mathbb{A}=\mathbb{R^*}$ (the set of the hyperreals) ?

Comment: Well, I guess so, since the real number line is submerged into the hyperreal one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We *can* make it a convention that we would only use $+\infty$ in that way. For example, the natural interpretation (via transfer) of that symbol in non-standard analysis is, in fact, the largest extended hyperreal.

This isn't too different from the idea that we often use symbols $1$ and $0$ to denote the largest and smallest elements in a [bounded lattice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_%28order%29).

It would even be reasonable, in the construction where we take an ordered set and adjoin a new element and extend the ordering so the new element is the largest element, to adopt the convention that we use $+\infty$ as the name for this new element.

However, if we are using $+\infty$ to refer to a specific object with a prior meaning, then we can't always assume it is the largest element of an ordered set. For example, we can construct an ordered set $(S, <)$ defined by

- $S = \overline{\mathbf{R}} \cup \{ \star \}$
- $x < y$ is true if and only if ($x,y \in \overline{\mathbf{R}}$ and $x<y$ as extended real numbers) or ($y = \star$)

In this example, we would have $+\infty < \star$.

Or for a more amusing example, we could use the ordered set $(\overline{\mathbf{R}}, >)$; that is, we take the extended real numbers and reverse the ordering. This is still an ordered set, and $+\infty$ is its *smallest* element.